# How to write php script to render html to another fille?

Tags: php, html, crud, separation-of-concerns

I have another php newbie question:
I writing a CRUD web app. I have a php file that will fetch data from database and saves the results as variables. Based on search results its rendering some html.

// after fetching data from database:

```
    if (isset($_REQUEST['search'])) {
    if (!$personnel && !$location && !$department) {
        echo 'No results to show!';
    } elseif ($personnel) {
?>

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Job Title</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Action</th>


                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
            foreach ($output['data']['personnel'] as $row) :;
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="hidden"><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['lastName'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['firstName'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['jobTitle'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['department'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['location'] ?></td>


                    <td><button class="btn btn-info editPersonnel">Edit</button>
                        <a href="deletePersonnel.php?delete=<?php echo $row['lastName'] ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Personnel</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </table>
```

and so on.

Can someone tell me please how to change this script so it will render that table on my index page?
Workflow should be:
User typing something in the search box, the script is fetching the data, data is displayed on index page.

Thanks people!

Chi Chi

Comment: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-start-with-php

Comment: Question is a bit to vague currently. Can you narrow down issue? Additional, but unrelated to asked question, deleting based solely on last name will likely cause you issues down the road. Should delete based on an id.

Comment: Add the code to index.php using include

Comment: Ok, it looks like the problem I have can be easily sorted with jQuery and Ajax. Thanks, everyone!